# Compilation error of simple java files with Google Protocol Buffer

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

[Google protocol buffer/java](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)

I am new to maven and Google Protocol Buffer.

I followed all the README instructions and successfully built the files with Maven.

I got all the files in

> protobuf-2.4.1\java\target

(what is the use of this?)
The test cases run fine.

I compiled the meta data in the proto file and got the class files generated automatically here:

> com\example\tutorial\AddressBookProtos.java

I created two java files:
AddPerson.java and ListPeople.java from the code in the tutorial.

[image: eclipse screenshot]

I am not able to execute it. Where did I go wrong?

EDIT:

> The method mergeFrom(Message) from the type
>   AddressBookProtos.AddressBook.Builder refers to the missing type
>   Message

the second error:

> The method writeTo(CodedOutputStream) from the type
>   AddressBookProtos.AddressBook refers to the missing type
>   CodedOutputStream

These are from the AddPerson.java

AddressBookProtos.java has 100's of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screen shot it does not look like you have imported the generated classes to your project. Add all generated .java files to the correct location in your src folder and re-try.

Comment: I put the generated .java files. Even then I had problems. "package com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos does not exist. Then I ran the protoc on descriptor.proto and got the files. Hope this helps someone with similar issues.

Comment: You are right redmave. The DescriptorProtos file has to be created to fix the compilation errors. This worked out for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a compilation error.
Hold your cursor over the error in the IDE (Eclipse) and post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

First I don't know anything about this google project but anyways.
If its maven try this in the command prompt where your pom.xml is.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

It should generate project files then import the project in eclipse.